# Adding values to specific locations in an initialized array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

Thanks in advance--new to programming and SO! I am trying to add values to specific locations in an array. Here is what I have tried, in which i try to add values to the initialized array in the format array[i][j]=value. It returns the error "IndexError: list index out of range".

```
ydata=[[None]*len(x_values)]*len(unit_id_values)
for i in range (len(x_values)):
    for j in range (len(unit_id_values)):
        for unit in list_Unit_A:
            if unit.filename_integer==x_values[i] and unit.unit_id==unit_id_values[j]:
                ydata[i][j]=unit.data_dict[metric]
            else:
                continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out what ydata is for you.  If I do something similar to your first line I get this:

```
>>> ydata = [[None] * 2] * 3
>>> ydata
[[None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]
```

Your first loop is actually iterating over the size of each of your inner lists but it is referencing the outer list if that makes sense.  Your second loop is iterating over the size of the outer list but is referencing elements of the inner lists.  So basically you have the loop/indexing flip flopped.

Try

```
ydata[j][i]=unit.data_dict[metric]
```

Instead of

```
ydata[i][j]=unit.data_dict[metric]
```

Comment: That was of course the issue! Thanks for catching my silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet you have shown.

ydata is the matrix where the rows size is length of unit_id_values and
columns size is length of x_values but in your code you are accessing the row using the column index and column using the row index, which is wrong and therefore  results in the error "IndexError: list index out of range , when the indexes are out of range.

therefore your code should be like this:

```
ydata=[[None]*len(x_values)]*len(unit_id_values)

for i in range (len(unit_id_values)):     //this is row
    for j in range (len(x_values)):       // this is column
        for unit in list_Unit_A:
            if unit.filename_integer==x_values[j] and unit.unit_id==unit_id_values[i]:
                ydata[i][j]=unit.data_dict[metric]
            else:
                continue
```

or in another way you can write the code this way also:

```
ydata=[[None]*len(x_values)]*len(unit_id_values)

for i in range (len(x_values)):                 //this is column
    for j in range (len(unit_id_values)):       // this is row
        for unit in list_Unit_A:
            if unit.filename_integer==x_values[i] and unit.unit_id==unit_id_values[j]:
                ydata[j][i]=unit.data_dict[metric]
            else:
                continue
```

Comment: That was of course the issue! Thanks for catching my silly mistake.